# Order of choices in filter drop-down

Tags: list, filter

In a list, at the filter drop-down section, choices are in ascending order:
[image]

Is it possible to display the choices in descending order? (It would be more comfortable because users usually choose the last 3-4 dates and now they have to roll down to get them.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Display column in descending order:

- Go to *List Settings*
- Modify the View
- In *Group By* >> Select column & check *Show groups in descending order*

Comment: Your answer does not address the question. xor139 wants to change the order of the filter options, not the order of displayed items. So far, I have only seen this done through javascript on the page. See related question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137084/how-to-change-the-order-of-filter-in-reverse-order