# how to change the order of filter in reverse order?

Tags: list, list-view

[image]

This is my demo list, and I want to apply filter to it. However, notice that the order of the filter is alphabetic, but I want it in reverse. How can I make the order of the filter in reverse order?

ie.

```
havefun
have fun
haha
...
```

I have no idea how to describe this problem.

Comment: select the Descending from the that drop down

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE it will make the title sorted not the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a filter to your list and then right above the filter there is a sort option that you can use to sort the results in reverse order.. Maybe I'm not understanding the issue correctly?

[image]

Comment: The sort is going to sort the items and the filter will reduce the number of sorted items shown..

Comment: i don't want to apply filter, i just want to change the default order.

Answer (score 1):

With some javascript added to the view (either jslink, scripteditor, contentwebpart, customaction) it is achievable.

I tested this on an on-premise 2013 environment with September 2016 CU installed.

Since the javascript solution is overriding core javascript functionality its recommended to test this every time you update SharePoint.

```
function FilterOMenu(c, a) {
    //Be carefull with overriding SharePoint core functions, for now this will work (September 2016 CU). Ensure you test this every time after installing a SharePoint update.
    //SharePoint default (I placed this above, cause it returns.)
    if (a == null)
        return;
    var b = a.tagName == "DIV" ? a.parentNode : a;
    //End SharePoint default

    //Custom implementation to sort the filter
    var fieldInternalName = a.getAttribute("name");

    //some sort functions
    var ascComparer = function(a,b){return a.text<b.text ? -1:a.text>b.text ? 1 : 0;};
    var descComparer = function(a,b){return a.text>b.text ? -1:a.text<b.text ? 1 : 0;};
    var ascDateComparer = function(a,b){d1 = Date.parse(a.text);d2 = Date.parse(b.text);return d1<d2 ? -1:d1>d2 ? 1 : 0;};
    var descDateComparer = function(a,b){d1 = Date.parse(a.text);d2 = Date.parse(b.text);return d1>d2 ? -1:d1<d2 ? 1 : 0;};

    var myCustomSort = {};
    //Add the field internal name and give a comparer as value to sort
    //As example the title column as your case is
    myCustomSort["LinkTitle"] = descComparer;
    myCustomSort["Title"] = descComparer;


    if(typeof c != "undefined" && c != null && typeof myCustomSort[fieldInternalName] != "undefined"){//check if you implemented a custom sort for the current internalname
        //select all items that are checkable (the options)
        var allSelectableItems = c.querySelectorAll('[checked]');
        if(allSelectableItems.length > 0){
            var elementInnerhtmls = [];
            var htmlToReplace = "";
            var htmlToAppend = "";
            for(var i = 0;i<allSelectableItems.length;i++)
            {
                elementInnerhtmls.push({text: allSelectableItems[i].getAttribute("text"),html:allSelectableItems[i].outerHTML});
                htmlToReplace += allSelectableItems[i].outerHTML; 
            }
            elementInnerhtmls = elementInnerhtmls.sort(myCustomSort[fieldInternalName]);
            for(var i = 0;i<elementInnerhtmls.length;i++)
            {
                htmlToAppend += elementInnerhtmls[i].html;
            }
            //replace the original html with the sorted html
            c.innerHTML = c.innerHTML.replace(htmlToReplace,htmlToAppend);
        }
    }
    //SharePoint default
    OMenu(c, b, null, null, -1)
    //End SharePoint default
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this on October 2016 CU, but it doesn't seem to work. As I understand, then I should use value from `name` tag not from `DisplayName` tag?  Should it work, that I but this code in script editor on list page and by selecting that field, it should be filtered?

Comment: Edit: seems, that this script doesn't run if I just put it in `scirpt editor`

Comment: Inside the script editor you also should use script tags in order to run the script <script type="text/javascript">{code above}</script>

Comment: This script seems to work while on `Edit page`, but not when just navigating to list page itself.