# SharePoint 2013 Foundation Sort Filters Values on Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, filter

**Problem**

I have a date field, where there are lot's of dates to filter by, but I would need, that they'd show in different order. Originally they are sorted oldest first, but I would need to turn it newest first.

[image]

**What I want to do**

So there are currently 4 different dates on picture above. first date is 8.09.2016 and last 26.01.2017. Now I would need to sort those dates other way around, so they would start from 26.01.2017 .. 8.09.2016

Is it possible to achieve this and how?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Can't you just click Descending?

Comment: @Submits choosing Ascending or Descending only filters the list, but not the choices displayed in red circle

Comment: You might find this useful: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137084/how-to-change-the-order-of-filter-in-reverse-order/137088

Comment: This seems to be the thing I'm looking for indeed, but I can't get it to work some why.. Added comments to that answer there as well