# Sharepoint Lists: Order of choices in filter drop-down

Tags: list

In a list, at the filter drop-down section, choices are in ascending order.

Is it possible to display the choices in descending order?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB SharePoint doesn't give us an option to change the order to descending. You have to try with JavaScript added to the view (either jslink, scripteditor, contentwebpart, customaction). For more information using JavaScript refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137084/how-to-change-the-order-of-filter-in-reverse-order) link.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.